# Pandas Dataframe, check condition and return value to same index

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['Umbrella,handlX', 'Matress', 'Badminton,shuttlX', 'Shuttle'], }) 

             Product
0    Umbrella,handlX
1            MatrXss
2  Badminton,shuttlX
3            Shuttle
```

search for "X" and if found replace it with e using user defined function.

Output as given below:

```
             Product
0    Umbrella,handle
1            Matress
2  Badminton,shuttle
3            Shuttle
```